# Want to join last row of two dataframe on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
quantity:          
a   b   c
3   1   nan
3   2   8
7   5   9
4   8   nan

price
34
```

I have two dataframes quantity and price and I want to join last row of quantity dataframe to price where `c` is not `nan`

I wrote these query but didn't got the desired output:

`price = pd.concat(price,quantity["a","b","c"].tail(1).isnotnull())`

what I want is like:

```
price a b c
34    7 5 9
```

Comment: @jezrael can help me out??

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need remove missing values and for last row - added double `[]` for one row DataFrame:

```
df=pd.concat([price.reset_index(drop=True),
             quantity[["a","b","c"]].dropna(subset=['c']).iloc[[-1]].reset_index(drop=True)], 
             axis=1)
print (df)
   price  a  b    c
0     34  7  5  9.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (quantity[["a","b","c"]].dropna().iloc[[-1]])
   a  b    c
2  7  5  9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dfs are these:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,1,np.nan], [3,2,8], [7,5,9], [4,8,np.nan]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([34], columns=['price'])
```

You can do in this way:

```
final_df = pd.concat([df.dropna(subset=['c']).tail(1).reset_index(drop=True), df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c  price
0  7  5  9.0     34
```

Answer (score 0):

I would filter the `df` on `not null` then simply add the price to it:

```
new_df = df[df['c'].notnull()]
```

Where c is your column name.

```
new_df['price'] = 32  # or the price from your df
```